# How can I configure wildcard/catchall domains in OpenShift Online?

Tags: openshift, wildcard-subdomain, catch-all

My app handles a ton of sub-domains (www.example.org, foo.example.org, bar.example.org, ...).

Due to the *big amount* and the fact that the sub-domains are determined based on *regular exports from another system*, it would be virtually impossible to manually add all of them as OpenShift Online domain aliases.

***Is there a way to configure OpenShift to do a catch all?***

So far I've tried entering things like `*.example.org`, `@.example.org` and `.example.org`, but OpenShift says "The specified alias is not allowed"

Comment: I don't believe that is going to be possible with OpenShift Online. You might try submitting a support ticket to OpenShift to see if they can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

OpenShift Online does not currently support wildcard subdomains.  You would have to add each domain as a separate alias.  I would suggest you use subfolders instead of subdomains (www.example.com/username instead of username.example.com)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this was just added recently or you didnt find it, but I think you are looking for this:

```
*.example.com. 300 IN  A 192.168.133.2
```

https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/install/prerequisites.html#environment-requirements